# Assigning a volume to a sphere

Tags: matlab

I'm generating a series of spheres (call them *m* ) inside a plot in MATLAB. Then, I'm generating another sphere around some of these (call it *j* ).

Basically, I'm just trying to figure out how many (not necessarily an integer) of *m* are within *j*.

The way I thought I'd have to go about solving it was figuring out a way to assign a volume to the *m* spheres, so that I can figure out how much of the "volume" of these spheres is contained inside of *j*. I am technically using the default radius of 1 for these spheres, so I do already know the volume of both. The problem is I'm generating approximately 100 of *m*. I won't be able to count them visually to know exactly how many are within *j*. Also, sometimes only parts of the *m* spheres are within *j*, which would mean I'd have to estimate if I did it manually.

Would anyone have any ideas? I'd really appreciate it. I apologize if it's a basic question (novice MATLAB user)...I've tried for quite a few hours to find a way to figure it out.

The basic code I'm following:

**For j**

```
j = surfl(x*r, y*r, z*r);
```

**For m**

```
for n = 1:length(position_new)
    B.index(n).location = position_new(n,:);
end 
    [x,y,z] = sphere(10);
for n = 1:length(position)
    hold on 
    m(n,1) = surfl(x-B.index(n).location(1), y-B.index(n).location(2),...
        z-B.index(n).location(3)); 
end
```

Comment: There is a simple part you can implement. Let `jr` be the radius of the large sphere and `mr` the radi of the small spheres. If the distance between both centers is larger or equal than `jr+mr(i)` the spheres do not intersect. If the distance between both centers is smaller or equal to `jr-mr(i)` the smaller sphere is fully contained in the larger one.

Comment: @Daniel -- The second part of what you said  `jr-mr(i)` worked marvelously. Thank you!! The second part I'm still having a little trouble with... _j_ could still intersect the sphere but not go through the center of _m_. This would be a really good estimate though, but even using it as an estimate, how would I go about figuring out the fraction of the non-whole _m_ spheres within _j_ ? The way that it's running now, I'm getting a true/false statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the volume as a measure of how much a small sphere is inside the large sphere you can use this code:

We assume that `jr` and `j_center` are the radius of sphere `j` and its centre respectively, and `mr(i)`, `m_centre(i)` are the  i-th small sphere radius and centre.

```
spheres_counter = 0;
for i=1:N_spheres
   d = norm(j_center - m_center);   %distance between 2 enters
   %check if the sphere if fully inside/outside the large sphere
   if d < jr - mr(i)
       %completely inside j
       spheres_counter = spheres_counter + 1;
   else if d < jr + mr(i)
       %partially inside j
       V_intersection = pi*(jr + mr(i) - d)^2 * (d^2 + 2*d*mr(i) - 3*mr(i)^2 + 2*d*jr + 6*mr(i)*jr - 3*jr^2)/(12 * d);
       % V_intersection is the intersection volume (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere-SphereIntersection.html)
       V_m = (4/3)*pi*mr(i)^3;
       spheres_counter = spheres_counter + V_intersection/V_m; 
   end
end
```